# How to change state of app in django from client side

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django (in server side programing in general) and I don't know how to declare a state and be able to update it from client side.
What I want to do is be able for some users to set a "maintenance" state (boolean) to true or false.

I'm using [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Can someone give me a clue or documentation to read?

Thanks

Comment: Please describe further. Are you maybe talking about a database? Web development is different as any state is only held between the request and the response (you usually don't operate in the main loop - it's handling requests). To keep a state between requests one usually uses a database (Django supports SQLite, MySQL and Postgres out of the box). An exciting journey awaits you :)

Comment: Yes I'm using a database (Postgres), I'm building a table with only one value to keep this state, but I was wondering if there was an other way to do so. I guess it isn't !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments under your question I assume we're discussing a maintenance mode of the whole service. 
This would usually be done by the service infront of your application, i.e. nginx, which you need for other things as well.
But since you need the site admins to be able to trigger it you could store that value in a cache service.
One of them would be **Redis** which works nicely with **Django's cache framework**. You could make a custom **middleware** that would check for that maintenance value in Redis and throw the maintenance page.
A middleware would be optimal as it will ensure the whole service (all URLs) are kept hidden if maintenance mode is on.